# Spark on Hbase Jars

Tags: apache-spark, hbase, cloudera, apache-spark-2.0

I am trying to run an example of SparkOnHbase as mentioned here -> 
[Spark On Hbase](https://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2015/08/apache-spark-comes-to-apache-hbase-with-hbase-spark-module/)

But i am just trying to compile and run the code on my local windows machine.
My build.sbt snippet below

```
scalaVersion := "2.11.8"

libraryDependencies +="org.apache.spark" % "spark-core_2.11" % "2.1.0"
libraryDependencies += "com.typesafe" % "config" % "1.3.1"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.hbase" % "hbase-client" % "1.3.1"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.hbase" % "hbase-server" % "1.3.1"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.hbase" % "hbase-common" % "1.3.1"
```

And as mentioned in the Link i am just trying to put this code :

```
val hbaseContext = new HBaseContext(sc, config)
rdd.hbaseBulkDelete(hbaseContext,
                  tableName,
                  putRecord => new Delete(putRecord),
                  4)
```

But i am not even getting HbaseContext. I don't know which package to import

Answer (score 0):

I use Maven, but dependencies should be the same. I assume you are missing this dependency:

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.apache.hbase</groupId>
<artifactId>hbase-spark</artifactId>
<version>1.2.0-cdh5.7.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I did not any such dependency by name hbase-spark on maven website. I am not looking for a cloudera version as of now

Comment: Actually I use Cloudera version

Comment: Well i can try with the Cloudera Version too let me know the dependencies that worked for u

Comment: Hello, did that help @AJm I am mapr user and i am facing the same problem. My spark hbase dependency version is <version>2.0.0-alpha4</version>